# Cartesian Product + Union

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

Hi stack exchange I am currently taking a Discrete Structures class and I was wondering if I had the logic on this homework problem I had right. I couldn't find examples of this problem in my book or in lecture so I just thought I would ask if I am in the right direction

**Let A = {a, b}, B = {x, y}, and C = {0,1}
(B × B) ∪ ( C × A)**

If

**B X B is {(x,x),(x,y)(y,x)(y,y)}**

And:

**C X A is {(0,a)(0,b)(1,a)(1,b)}**

I am confused on what their union would be?
Would it simply be them added together one to one
Like the first one would be:
{(0,a,x,x)}?

Or would it just be one giant set of them all added up together? 
I would appreciate some pointers on how to do this problem as I feel neither of my assumptions make sense.

Comment: or maybe the every set from the right side would be added to every individual set on the left?

Comment: Just making sure: the question is "What is $(B \times B) \cup (C \times A)$?", right?

Comment: @neofelis Yes, that is what it is asking. Sorry that I didn't make it more clear.

Answer (score 1):

It's the second one, meaning
$$(B \times B) \cup (C \times A) = \{(x,x),(x,y),(y,x),(y,y),(0,a),(0,b),(1,a),(1,b)\}$$
The union of two sets just is the set containing every element of the first set and every element of the second set (and nothing else).

Why is $(0,a,x,x)$ not in your union? Simply because it's not in either set. In the early stages of dealing with cartesian products it might help you to remember that the union of two sets will contain the same sorts of things as the sets themselves. The union of a set of apples and a set of pears will contain apples and pears; the union of a set of (only) apples and another set of (only) apples will contain only apples. Similarly, and more relevantly, the union of a set of (only) ordered pairs and a set of (only) ordered pairs will contain only ordered pairs -- never a quadruple. But this is really a consequence of what a union is -- all the things which are in either set *and nothing else* -- rather than a more basic fact.